# Remove unicode string and spaces from json response

Tags: java, regex, jackson, httpurlconnection

I am calling a webservice which gives me Json Response. Here is the code

```java
URL url = new URL(strUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
...
//get response text
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));           
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((respText = br.readLine()) != null) {                
    response.append(respText);
}
br.close(); 
retValue = response.toString();
```

The problem is response is like the following

```
"{\u000d\u000a  \"groups\": [\u000d\u000a    {\u000d\u000a      \"signingGroupId\": \"323793\",\u000d\u000a      \"groupName\": \"1440 Signing Group 1\",\u000d\u000a      \"groupType\": \"sharedSigningGroup\",\u000d\u000a      \"created\": \"3\/27\/2019 6:08:34 AM\",\u000d\u000a      \"createdBy\": \"ABC Software\",\u000d\u000a      \"modified\": \"4\/1\/2019 6:40:45 AM\",\u000d\u000a      \"modifiedBy\": \"Corner O'Brien\"\u000d\u000a    },\u000d\u000a    {\u000d\u000a      \"signingGroupId\": \"323794\",\u000d\u000a      \"groupName\": \"1440 Another Group\",\u000d\u000a      \"groupType\": \"sharedSigningGroup\",\u000d\u000a      \"created\": \"3\/27\/2019 6:14:52 AM\",\u000d\u000a      \"createdBy\": \"XYZ Software\",\u000d\u000a      \"modified\": \"3\/27\/2019 6:16:37 AM\",\u000d\u000a      \"modifiedBy\": \"XYZ Software\"\u000d\u000a    }\u000d\u000a  ]\u000d\u000a}"
```

I want to make respose like this from the above response

```
"{"groups":[{"signingGroupId": "323793","groupName": "1440 Signing Group 1","groupType": "sharedSigningGroup","created": "3/27/2019 6:08:34 AM","createdBy": "ABC Software","modified": "4/1/2019 6:40:45 AM","modifiedBy": "John O'Brien"},{"signingGroupId": "323794","groupName": "1440 Another Group","groupType": "sharedSigningGroup","created": "3/27/2019 6:14:52 AM","createdBy": "ABC Software","modified": "3/27/2019 6:16:37 AM","modifiedBy": "ABC Software"}]}"
```

That is to remove all the `\u000d\u000a` and `spaces` after that. But not to remove space from any of the Json Property.

I tried this

```java
retValue = retValue.replace("\\u000d\\u000a", "");
retValue = retValue.replace("\\", "");
```

which gives me

```
"{  "groups": [    {      "signingGroupId": "323793",      "groupName": "1440 Signing Group 1",      "groupType": "sharedSigningGroup",      "created": "3/27/2019 6:08:34 AM",      "createdBy": "ABC Software",      "modified": "4/1/2019 6:40:45 AM",      "modifiedBy": "John O'Brien"    },    {      "signingGroupId": "323794",      "groupName": "1440 Another Group",      "groupType": "sharedSigningGroup",      "created": "3/27/2019 6:14:52 AM",      "createdBy": "XYZ Software",      "modified": "3/27/2019 6:16:37 AM",      "modifiedBy": "XYZ Software"    }  ]}"
```

But still there are spaces. Now If I use

```java
String replcaedNewLineAndSpaces = retValue.replaceAll("[ \t]+", "");
```

Problem is with this line is it also removes spaces from the Json Properties.

```
"{"groups":[{"signingGroupId":"323793","groupName":"1440SigningGroup1","groupType":"sharedSigningGroup","created":"3/27/20196:08:34AM","createdBy":"ABCSoftware","modified":"4/1/20196:40:45AM","modifiedBy":"JohnO'Brien"},{"signingGroupId":"323794","groupName":"1440AnotherGroup","groupType":"sharedSigningGroup","created":"3/27/20196:14:52AM","createdBy":"XYZSoftware","modified":"3/27/20196:16:37AM","modifiedBy":"XYZSoftware"}]}"
```

See groupName which was `"groupName": "1440 Signing Group 1"`. Now becomes 
`1440SigningGroup1`. Similarly for other properties.

Is there anyway It keeps the Json String as it is but remove `\u000d\u000a` and `spaces` after it. So the final response become

```
"{"groups":[{"signingGroupId": "323793","groupName": "1440 Signing Group 1","groupType": "sharedSigningGroup","created": "3/27/2019 6:08:34 AM","createdBy": "ABC Software","modified": "4/1/2019 6:40:45 AM","modifiedBy": "John O'Brien"},{"signingGroupId": "323794","groupName": "1440 Another Group","groupType": "sharedSigningGroup","created": "3/27/2019 6:14:52 AM","createdBy": "ABC Software","modified": "3/27/2019 6:16:37 AM","modifiedBy": "ABC Software"}]}"
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, just parse the JSON.

Comment: The extra space shouldn't matter

Comment: You forgot `response.append(respText).append("\u000d\u000a");` for the line endings that are stripped in readLine. `\u000d` aka `\r` is the CR and `\u000a` aka `\n` is LF for the windows newline. If what you saw was in the IDE's debugger, then that could just be a representation as string, to be copy/pasted inside `"..."`. (So no action needed)

Comment: Do it in one go `retValue.replaceAll("\\\\u\\w{4}\\s*", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referred in the comments, creating a POJO class and parsing the JSON would be optimal and safe. (I think the most common library is [GSon library](https://github.com/google/gson))

However, if you insist removing spaces though, do it with a simple regex:

```
retValue.replaceAll("\\\\u000d\\\\u000a\\s*", "")
```

This will replace all strings starting with \u000d\u000a followed by 0-unlimited spaces.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was doing the same. I have Pojo and I was trying to map Json response on the Pojo. But I think because space I was getting error. I am using Jackson. Now here what I did and it got successfully mapped `retValue = retValue.replaceAll("\\\\u000d\\\\u000a\\s*", "");retValue = retValue.replace("\\", "");char ch = '\"';int posOfJ = retValue.indexOf(ch);int posOfi = retValue.lastIndexOf('\"');retValue = retValue.substring(posOfJ + 1, posOfi);signingGroupResponse = JsonUtil.convertJsonToObject(retValue, SigningGroupResponse.class);`  Thanks for your help